# getting error: Could not start Ghost Driver

Tags: javascript, selenium, phantomjs, openshift, ghostdriver

I'm trying to run `Ghostdriver` inside my Openshift server. As i run this command:

`./phantomjs --webdriver=15002`

It says:

```
PhantomJS is launching GhostDriver...
[ERROR - 2014-08-01T04:14:21.160Z] GhostDriver - main.fail - {"message":"Could not start Ghost Driver","line":82,"sourceId":139887801789952,"sourceURL":":/ghostdriver/main.js","stack":"Error: Could not start Ghost Driver\n    at :/ghostdriver/main.js:82","stackArray":[{"sourceURL":":/ghostdriver/main.js","line":82}]}
$ ./phantomjs --version
1.9.8
```

Please help me out, I'm getting this error from `10 Days`. I searched everything and googled everything. nothing is sorted me out :( I'm much upset :(

*Help surely would be appreciated!!*

Comment: I have never used the driver option. Your problem might be a port issue. Here is a copy and paste answer about ports on openshift from Corey. The only ports that are publicly available are 80/443/8000/8443, and your application must bind to port 8080 on your OPENSHIFT__IP to be able to be reached using your app-domain.rhcloud.com public url. You can check out this article to read more about how all of the binding and routing works: https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-port-binding-routing.html

Comment: I saw in the phantomjs bug reports that someone else reported the same problem. Maybe it's broken. Ask a question on phantomjs.org.

Answer (score 1):

OpenShift doesn't allow binding the localhost address; there is [a patch](https://github.com/laurentj/ghostdriver/commit/e7bb101a8eb282ebf6e42ca79dcd25d544cfd35b) to allow GhostDriver to bind any specified IP (currently it always binds to localhost no matter what), but it still hasn't made it in the PhantomJS source tree and binary distributions.

In order to use PhantomJS + GhostDriver on OpenShift I recompiled it after applying the patch, you can find it here: https://paolobernardi.wordpress.com/2015/02/25/phantomjs-with-ghostdriver-on-openshift/

Answer (score 1):

Check the Port Number while running the below command. Might be your port say 5555 is already in used. So change that if you get this "Could not start Ghost Driver" error

```
phantomjs --webdriver=5555
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation it looks like you should be able to do something like this:

```
./phantomjs --webdriver=$OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP:15002
```

You may have to actually type in your ip address there, not sure if that env variable will populate correctly..

http://phantomjs.org/api/command-line.html

```
--webdriver starts in 'Remote WebDriver mode' (embedded GhostDriver): '[[:]]' (default '127.0.0.1:8910')
```

Comment: I tried everything!!!... Not working !!.. I googled and searched on web and Everything and still getting the same error :( .. It's `15 days` ..I'm having the same error.. Can you please tell me another way where i could contact them directly with openshift owner.. :( Please let me know?

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to make [Paolo Bernardi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4605096/paolo-bernardi)'s patch work, I always catched a segmentation fault. So I re-compiled it on an RHEL machine, and this one worked for me: http://christophe-maillard.com/phantomjs-1.9.8.patched/phantomjs.tar.gz

PS: see [Trying to run PhantomJS on OpenShift: cannot patch GhostDriver so that it can bind on the server IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30506496/trying-to-run-phantomjs-on-openshift-cannot-patch-ghostdriver-so-that-it-can-bi)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the phantomjs process isn't already running
`ps -ef | grep phantom`