# Issue launching Phantomjs Selenium Web Driver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I'm using phantom.js driver for selenium in some java code.
It's a large project so i'll only copy what I think is the relevant code.

I had it working fine with the firefox driver.

I instantiate it here:

```
     Capabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
                ((DesiredCapabilities) caps).setJavascriptEnabled(true);
                ((DesiredCapabilities) caps).setCapability("takesScreenshot", true);
                ((DesiredCapabilities) caps).setCapability("timeoutInSeconds", 20);
                ((DesiredCapabilities) caps).setCapability(
                        PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY,
                        "/Applications/phantomjs-2.0.0-macosx/bin/phantomjs"
                );
                WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);

driver.get(base_url+searchQuery.urlString());
```

Then when I run the program I get a list of errors:

```
    SEVERE: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 137 (Exit value: 137)
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.46.0', revision: '87c69e2', time: '2015-06-04 16:17:10'
System info: host: 'Dannys-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: '10.104.0.84', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.10.3', java.version: '1.7.0_79'
Driver info: driver.version: PhantomJSDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:242)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:141)
    at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver.<init>(PhantomJSDriver.java:115)
    at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver.<init>(PhantomJSDriver.java:104)
    at scrape.MyFreeMp3Adapter.performScrape(MyFreeMp3Adapter.java:63)
    at Main.main(Main.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '2.46.0', revision: '87c69e2', time: '2015-06-04 16:17:10'
System info: host: 'Dannys-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: '10.104.0.84', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.10.3', java.version: '1.7.0_79'
Driver info: driver.version: PhantomJSDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:170)
    at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSCommandExecutor.execute(PhantomJSCommandExecutor.java:78)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:578)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:36316/status] to be available after 20006 ms
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:104)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:167)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedTimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:143)
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:79)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:201)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:130)
    ... 16 more
```

Its seems like it can't get the driver server to start.

Comment: Are you allowed to bind on localhost?

Comment: As far as I can nothing else is binding to locals host, is there something in specific I should check?

Comment: Well, for example on [OpenShift](https://www.openshift.com/), you're not allowed to bind on localhost, but PhantomJS's GhostDriver can only bind on localhost. This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30506496/1225328