# ExBuild: PhantomJS sass build exited with code : 137

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, model-view-controller, extjs, sencha-cmd

I'm facing some problem like below while developing an web app using the command

```
      $ Sencha app build development
```

and it throws some exceptions likes

```
ExBuild: PhantomJS sass build exited with code : 137
```

i 'm unable to understand what does it mean and how can i get rid off these problem. my system is ubuntu 14.0 and Sencha ExtJs 6.0.2. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`sass` (Syntactically Awesome Style Sheet) is an extension to CSS that makes it easy to write and maintain CSS, but is not supported by browsers.

A "PhantomJS sass build" refers to the process of compilation of SASS (which is nice to write) into CSS (which browsers understand), done in the 3rd party product PhantomJS (which is a "headless browser", a browser without GUI).

Inside PhantomJS, which doesn't understand SCSS either, runs a javascript code called "Sencha Fashion", a so-called "transpiler" that converts SASS to CSS.

Now, your version of PhantomJS throws error 137, which is a pain to find out without a concise error message. You can check [whether you have enough free system memory](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?278735-Error-sencha-app-build-Ubuntu) and [which version of PhantomJS is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31532630/issue-launching-phantomjs-selenium-web-driver) and [possibly revert to an older version](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?310446-6.1.2.15-How-to-disable-PhantomJS), to name [a few possibilities a short google search has brought up](https://www.google.de/search?q=PhantomJS+error+137).